# Creating CPC ads using Facebook API 2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

According to Facebook's blog post, to create a CPC campaign using the new 2.4 API, we create the campaign with billing_event=LINK_CLICKS and optimization_goal=LINK_CLICKS.

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2015/07/08/marketing-api-v2_4/

I did that.  When I look at the campaign in the Facebook Power Editor, when I look at the edit dialogue for the campaign, it says under "Optimization & Pricing" that the campaign is optimized for CPA.  Two options above that is "Clicks: We'll serve your ads to people who might click on your ad (CPC)".

So I'm confused, what's the difference between CPA where the action is link clicks versus CPC?  Does this have to do with the change where CPC now just counts link clicks instead of any kind of engagement?  Is "CPA" correct and they're just using confusing terminology, or is the documentation wrong, or some implementation on my side or their side that's wrong?

I would post a screenshot of the Power Editor view that I'm talking about but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: I also posted this question on Facebook help community and will post here if I get a response there.

Comment: Does this page help clarify the changes? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/optimization_simplification#v2_3_to_v2_4

Comment: I think it's the terminology that's confusing me, especially trying to match up the API with what's in the Facebook UI.  In fact, between the time I posted the original question and now, the Facebook UI has updated some of their verbiage, which I believe has made it more clear, because it now distinguishes between "Link Clicks to Website / Pay per Impressions" and "Link Clicks to Website / Pay per Link Click".

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has updated its terminology in the Ads Manager and Power Editor and removed the term CPA.  When I create a campaign with billing_event=LINK_CLICKS and optimization_goal=LINK_CLICKS, the "Optimization & Pricing" section in the Facebook UI now says "Link Clicks to Website / Pay per Link Click => We'll deliver  your ad to people who are more likely to click in your ad, and you'll pay per link click (CPC)" which is behavior that I expect.

It's still odd that they have another option called "Clicks => We'll serve your ads to people who might click on your ad (CPC)" but I'm guessing what that means is that they're optimizing based on who might click, but you're still paying by impressions.